# How does following relation generates Lorentz generator?

Tags: special-relativity, group-theory, representation-theory, dirac-matrices

In Schwartz book sec 10.3, Schwartz says following:

> The Lorentz generators when acting on Dirac spinors can be written as $$S^{\mu \nu}=\frac{i}{4}[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}]$$

But what I am able to understand from reading chapter $10$ (Spinors) is that generator of Lorentz group when acted on $4$-vectors are the the six matrices $J_i$ and $K_i$. And no I don't understand how he gives the rank-$2$ tensor representation of Lorentz group,$V^{\mu \nu}$ (Eq $10.2$). It is given as a fact and he doesn't give any hint to derive it as he did for vector representation.

Since I don't understand rank $2$ tensor representation, I can't follow his logic in connecting $S^{\mu \nu}$ with $V^{\mu \nu}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $K^i$ are the $S^{0i}$ and the $J^i= \epsilon^{ijk} S^{jk}/2$. It's just like the connection of the $E$ and $B$ field to $F^{\mu\nu}$.

Comment: Oh! I see it's just embedding of $K_i$ and $J_i$ into $S^{\mu\nu}$ nothing extra is going on, right?

Comment: Yes. It's just a relabelling of the generators to separate the $K$ boost from the space rotations $J$.